# Can't find my conda environment

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda in ubuntu using the following [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9SWJx2FZHQ). I installed all my python packages in "my_env". Now we I restart the system I can't get into my conda environment. I'm at

```
root@username:
```

And tried `source activate my_env`

```
bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

When I tried `conda info --envs .`

I got the error: `conda: command not found`
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't put `export PATH=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` command in my bashrc file.

This guy didnt mention it in his piece.

So, once install environment, edit bashrc file by

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

paste : `export PATH=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`

save it

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And we are done!